# You are being redirected. Rails 5 + Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My rails application successfully logs out a user and redirects to the about page when in development mode. But the moment i deploy it to production it returns a 302 status and a page that shows "you are being redirected". Am using devise for authentication below is what my code actually looks like.

The routes

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations", confirmations: "users/confirmations", sessions: "devise/sessions" }, skip: [:sessions]

  devise_scope :user do
        get "login" => "devise/sessions#new", as: :new_user_session
        post "login" => "devise/sessions#create", as: :user_session
        get "/join" => "users/registrations#new", as: :join
        get '/logout', to: "devise/sessions#destroy", as: :destroy_user_session
  end
  resources :companies

  get "/about", to: "pages#about"
  get "/faq", to: "pages#faq"
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
   root 'pages#home'
end
```

My application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

        protect_from_forgery with: :exception
        include SessionsHelper

        protected
        def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
                company_path(resource)
        end

        def after_sign_out_path_for(resource_or_scope)
                "/about"        
        end

        def store_location
                session[:return_to] == request.full_path
        end

        def clear_stored_location
                session[:return_to] = nil
        end

        def redirect_back_or_to(alternate)
                redirect_to(session[:return_to] || alternate)
                clear_stored_location
        end
end
```

And finally my link to log out.

```
<%= link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path %>
```

Please note that i am using devise 4.2.0 and capistrano for deployment.

Regards

~

Comment: could you add the entire content of `routes.rb`

Comment: @neydroid added entire content of routes.rb as requested

Answer (score 0):

I had to override devise sessions#controller and changed my routes to:

```
    delete 'logout', to: "users/sessions#destroy", as: :destroy_user_session
```

Then i added delete method to my link for logging out.